# JFreeChart-like in Delphi

Tags: java, delphi, charts, jfreechart

I have worked with JFreeChart in a few Java projects. I wonder if there is something similar I can use in Delphi for Win32 or if you know about a nice free chart library for Delphi. I'm working with Delphi 2006. I know there is already TChart but it looks a bit "old".
My researchs bring me to TMS Advanced Charts but it's too expensive for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can find some useful here
http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=195

Comment: Thanks for the link, Cesar. I think I'm going to check RiverSoftAVG: http://www.riversoftavg.com/charting.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can always build a Delphi wrapper for the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). Many such wrappers exist in [other languages](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api/web/useful-links-to-api-libraries).

Comment: Nice idea. Maybe not for this project but I'll see if I can do that in Delphi. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've already plumbed the depths of TChart I would suggest digging a little deeper.  I've found that with a little bit of styling you can get rid of that "old" look.  The default settings do look a little dated, but there's quite a bit of configurability there.   Maybe it would be worth exploring the TChart help docs and experimenting a little bit more if you haven't already.

Comment: I will look if I can change its look then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jfreechart, so I can't say whether there are similarities between it and my free dzchart component:

http://www.dummzeuch.de/delphi/dz-charts/english.html

Please be advised that I don't maintain it any more, so you are on your own.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to check it out.